# Strange behaviour of an activity on different android versions: map blinks

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-version

I have an activity which displays google map with some additional information. Also I have a service that downloads information from server and periodically informs activity that another portion of information is loaded using PendingIntent. 
On Android 4.0.3 everything works fine. But on Android 2.3.4 map in activity blinks (goes grey and than reloads) every time service informs this activity. 
Tried to track down if map is updated anywhere in onActivityResult, but it doesn't. 
Any help appreciated. Here is some code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == SERVICE_CACHED) {
        String fmId = data.getStringExtra("cachedId");
        if (dev.get(position).getId().equals(fmId)) {   //we still viewing the same device
            long[] dat = data.getLongArrayExtra("dates");
            ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
            for (int i=0; i<dat.length; i++) {
                dates.add(new Date(dat[i]));
            }

            addDates(fmId, dates, false, true);

//this is executed only once, as it meant to be
            if ((dispDate.getText() == null) || (dispDate.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                State state;
                synchronized(DBHelper.class) {
                    state = DBHelper.getState(fmId, dates.get(0).getTime());
                }


                updDispState(state);
            }
        }
    }
}


public void addDates(String fmId, ArrayList<Date> dates, boolean clear, boolean addTimesTo0) {
    if (dev.get(position).getId().equals(fmId)) {   //maybe user already changed selected device
        if (clear) {
            this.dates = dates;
        } else {
            this.dates.addAll(0, dates);
        }
        updDateSpinners(clear, dates, addTimesTo0);
    }
}
```

Service informs activity using this:

```
private void cache(LinkedList<State> statsAll, LinkedList<Long> datesAll) {
        if ((statsAll == null) || (statsAll.isEmpty()) || (datesAll == null) || (datesAll.isEmpty())) {
            return;
        }

        synchronized(DBHelper.class) {
            DBHelper.addStates(statsAll, fmId);
        }
        //inform MapActivity that new data is available
        long[] l = new long[datesAll.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
            l[i] = datesAll.get(i);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra("cachedId", fmId).putExtra("dates", l);
        try {
            pi.send(CacheService.this, MapActivity.SERVICE_CACHED, intent);
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {}          
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Doing some more testing I discovered that it's just map reloading itself on every onResume() call. How to stop it?
I put map in xml like this:

```
<fragment             
    android:id="@+id/mapF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

And retrieve it in code later

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapF)).getMap();
```

Comment: are you overriding onConfigurationChange? can you please provide the codes for updDispState(), updDateSpinners() and any other place where you are updating your map or the display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `onActivityResult` in this way from a service. Look into using a `BroadcastReceiver` instead. Your `Activity` class should register a broadcast listener, and your `Service` should send a broadcast `Intent` when new information is available.

Comment: not sure what you're talking about, 'cause I'm sending pending intent back to activity from service when information is available.

Comment: When you send the `PendingIntent` your Activity's lifecycle methods will be called, this is causing the strange behavior with your `MapFragment`. Using a `BroadcastReceiver` will allow your `Activity` to remain running uninterrupted and still receive results from your background `Service`. Use the `sendBroadcast` method from your `Service` and implement a receiver in your `Activity` class.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply, I'll try this approach and will accept your answer if it works. But my bounty is gone somewhere((

Comment: Really, you are a life saver! I thought I won't be able to get through this. Is there a way a can aword a bounty to you?

Comment: You've accepted my answer, which is fine. You could also upvote my answer. Really, I'm just glad it was helpful to you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem when I move the map (showing a menu) in android 4.0 it works fine but in 2.3 happens what you said. I couldn't do anything to fix it so my solution was use a relative layout and show the information in front of the map. I think that in "old versions" of android the map is not optimized for update in background and this is why he go black and update.

Comment: how do you update you relative layout when map is moved or zoom changed then? I need to draw a circle on a map, which need to stay on same coordinates and radius in meters whatever happens to a map.

Comment: you are talking about modify inside of the map drawing an overlay?

Comment: when you add an overlay it runs on the UI thread so I think that you can do nothing with it but you can try with an AsyncTask to prcess the information and after that show in the map. more or less there is an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744573/how-to-update-mapview-overlay-items-from-an-asynctask-without-arrayindexoutofbou

Comment: no, that's not what I meant. My overlay items blink along with the map every onResume() call. You suggested to use relative layout instead of overlay (if I understood you right). So map will still blink, but layout won't. But if user will zoom map in or out, all circles, displayed in layout, would become incorrect